# A corollary of the open mapping theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove the following corollary to the open mapping theorem (Theorem 2.6 in Brezis, to fix notation):

$\textbf{Corollary}$: Let $A: E \to F$ be a linear, bounded and surjective operator between Banach spaces, then
$ \exists C \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall y \in F, \exists x \in E$ satisfying $Ax = y$ and $|| x || \leq C || y ||$.

I am not sure how to use that $B^{F}(0, c) \subset A\left(B^{E}(0, 1)\right)$ here, since this would give an estimate on the norm of the image rather: any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

By the [Open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)) $A$ is an open map hence the set $A(B^E(0,1))$ is open and contains $A(0)=0$, so there exists some $\delta>0$ such that: $$B^F(0,\delta)\subset A(B^E(0,1)).\:\:\:\:\:\:(*)$$

Let $0<\delta'<\delta$ and define $C:=\frac{1}{\delta'}$, so given any $y\in F$: $$\left\|\frac{\delta'}{\|y\|}y\right\|\stackrel{\delta'<\delta}{\in} B^F(0,\delta)\subset A(B^E(0,1)),$$ hence there must be a $z\in B^E(0,1) $ such that: $$Az=\frac{\delta'}{\|y\|}y\implies A\left(\frac{\|y\|}{\delta'}z\right)= y,\;\; \text{lets define } x:= \frac{\|y\|}{\delta'}z.$$ Now this $x\in E$ satisfy the thesis: $$\|x\|=\frac{\|y\|}{\delta'}\|z\|\stackrel{z\in B(0,1)}{\le} \frac{1}{\delta'} \|y\|=C\|y\|. $$ And that $C>0$ is independent from the $y$'s choice.

Comment: I'd advise using `\| \|` for norms (example: $\|x\|$) instead of `|| ||` as it looks nicer, but that's merely a formatting nitpick. The proof is clear.